# Ubuntu 18.04.2 Static IP is set but also accessible via DHCP address

Tags: ubuntu, systemd-networkd

I have set a static ip on my Ubuntu server using netplan and it worked perfectly fine.

After a reboot the device is still accessible via the static ip I have set in /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml file like below

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
      p10p1:
        dhcp4: no
        addresses: [x.x.x.x/23]
        gateway4: x.x.x.x
        nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8]
```

Though am able to access server through x.x.x.x ip, when I grep for DHCP in journalctl, I can see there is DHCP assigned IP address showing up. I tried to access the server (ssh into it) using the DHCP assigned IP and surprisingly am able to access it and the IP address on login shows as x.x.x.x (static IP).

Just puzzled how both the IP are assigned to the same server and wanted to understand.

Comment: Are the static address and the dynamically assigned address on the same local network?  How about the address of the platform where you’re running the ``ssh`` command?  What does “the IP address on login shows as x.x.x.x (static IP).” mean?

Comment: can you provide a (sanitized as needed) view of the output of the command `ip addr show`?

Comment: do you happen to have both netplan and networkd enabled?  Do you have any content in `/etc/network/interfaces`?